# Blu-ray BD-R: Would you physically store it in a CaseLogic Wallet pocket?

Tags: storage, blu-ray, physical-environment

I keep several backup copies of my material and files. For my DVDs, one set of copies is kept in a CaseLogic wallet folder pack, so that I can easily move this around when visiting friends, family or for business. This is highly convenient. The other sets are kept in their jewel cases in hard plastic see thru storage boxes.

Although CaseLogic wallet material is designed to be abrasion free, their caveat is that external dust will be the cause of any blemishes. If hard dust gets in these pockets, which is inevitable, this will occasionally cause light hair like scratches on the disc surface as the discs are removed and returned for access to their contents. This is of no consequence as the laser and error correction can more than cope with this.

I'm aware that the blu-ray spec requires anti-scratch in disc surfaces but was wondering that, given the smaller pits, would dust and light scratches from wallet storage cause more problems with blu-rays than they would with DVDs? I'm using Blu-ray BD-R and BD-R DL write once media.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're over thinking this. My opinion is that they'll be fine, unless you'll be opening up the case inside of a coal mine and kicking it around on the floor. For general, normal use I don't think you have anything to worry about.

Comment: +1 For the coal mine scenario: it does make me see it as overthinking, agreed. Ticked as answered. I might as well go and try it: I have a 3 25Gb blu-rays BD-R copies of the same data - I'll put one in a wallet and see how I go. By the way, here's a related article about the potential perils of long-term archiving to optical discs: "Should you store treasured data on disks?": http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/programmes/click_online/8711747.stm

Comment: Thanks for the link. I had seen a reference to the article but hadn't tracked it down, now I don't have to.

Comment: +1 you're welcome @joeqwerty.